# Seeing The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken_L0lkU3J20" is not present in Internat Explorer but not Edge

Tags: cookies, microsoft-edge

I am testing a .Net Framework web application using the browsers on the web applications Windows Server 2019 host.

When using IE I get the error

`The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken_L0lkU3J20" is not present in Internet Explorer but not Edge`

on entering my credentials.

When using Edge this error does not occur.

Anyone got any idea as to why there might be a difference?

Thanks